# How do I run a list of CSV into a function?

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, csv

I am not sure how exactly to ask this question so please forgive my ignorance.

I am running a function from many files.  And after importing df I get the outcome into a csv file.

```
df=pd.read_csv("C:\Users\filename.csv ") 
years = 5
days = 365

out_put, productivity= timeresult.input_data.outbuild(df, year, days)

productivity.to_csv("Jan.csv")
```

However, this looks painfully to do for many CSV I am working with. So I managed to put all the csv file names into a big folder. And imported the csv files names into a list.

```
  filelist=["C:\Users\jan.csv", "C:\Users\feb.csv", "C:\Users\mar.csv"]
```

Would there be a way to have python loop all the list in the function and take the place of df and then send each file to a csv.

I tried this but failed

```
   filelist = []
   for x in filelist:
     out_put, productivity= timeresult.input_data.outbuild(x, year, days)
     filelist.append(productivity)
```

My goal was to have it run every cvs file name in the list and then create csv for each file.

Comment: You forgot to call `.to_csv()`?

Comment: I think if there is some mistakes in your code, please revise it.

Comment: `filelist=["C:\Users\jan.csv", "C:\Users\feb.csv", "C:\Users\mar.csv"]` will fail to run, because `backslash "\"` is an escape character.  Each path must be preceded by `r` (e.g. `r"C:\Users\jan.csv"`) or replace `"\"` with `/`.  I suggest using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) part of the standard library & [Python 3's pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/) to properly deal with your paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, this code is for you:

```
years = 5
days = 365
filelist = ["C:\Users\jan.csv", "C:\Users\feb.csv", "C:\Users\mar.csv"]
for filepath in filelist:
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
    out_put, productivity= timeresult.input_data.outbuild(df, year, days)

    df.index.name = filepath.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0]
    productivity.to_csv(filepath)
```

An example of the dataframe obtained could be the following:
From `jan.csv`:

```
     costPrice currencyCode endDateValid
jan                                     
0        83.56          GBP   2011-05-01
1        99.56          EUR   2017-05-01
```

From `feb.csv`:

```
     costPrice currencyCode endDateValid
feb                                     
0        93.89          EUR   2014-02-01
1        59.56          EUR   2012-07-01
```

**Tips**: If you want to get the list of names of all *.csv* files in the *"C:\Users\"* folder:

```
import glob
filelist = glob.glob("C:\Users\*.csv")
```

Comment: My only question now is there a way to have the index be the date name of the csv file like have the index be jan for the jan.csv used for the reference data?

Comment: This code run every cvs file name in the filelist and then create csv for each file. Also following my tip, you can create the filename list automatically. I do not know what you mean. Can you give an example?

Comment: thank so much. Sorry for the poor communication. The file name is the Date but there is no Date value on the data. So I want to add the Date name. But the Date name is only referenced in the file name. My goal was to have the cvs name be the index.

Comment: "My goal was to make the CVS name the index." as a dataframe index?

Comment: yes because the CVS name is where the Date is only referenced. so when it runs  out_put, productivity= timeresult.input_data.outbuild(df, year, days)  I want the index name of that result (productivity) to be the Date which is from the CVS name.

Comment: @safrade I have updated the answer, now every dataframe, and therefore also every csv that will be created, will have as the name of the index the name of the month obtained from the starting file.

Comment: really sorry but i got name 'filename' is not defined and changed it to filelist and got 'list' object has no attribute 'split.

Comment: Sorry with the copy and paste I confused "filepath" with "filename". Now I have corrected the code. The result is what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

You were so close, you used the location instead of the file. Use this code:

```
filelist=["C:\Users\jan.csv", "C:\Users\feb.csv", "C:\Users\mar.csv"]
for location in filelist:
    df = pd.read_csv(location)
    out_put, productivity= timeresult.input_data.outbuild(df, year, days)
    filelist.append(productivity)
```

Comment: Please discard my previous comment I got it resolved.  My only question now is there a way to have the index be the date name of the csv file like have the index be jan for the jan.csv used for the reference data?

Comment: You mean you want to iterate over a list like `["jan", "feb", "mar"] `,  which is created from the main list `filelist`.

Comment: yes. So to iterate over a list like ["jan", "feb", "mar"] but using the calculation out_put, productivity= timeresult.input_data.outbuild(df, year, days).

Comment: I can only help you you generate the list, would this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

#### To get a single, combined dataframe:

#### Create the dataframe with all `files`

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

p = Path(r'"C:\Users\name\Documents')  # set your path, don't end the path with "\"
files = p.glob('*.csv')  # find your files

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in files])
```

#### Apply to a function:

- This depends whether `timeresult.input_data.outbuild` accepts a dataframe.

```py
out_put, productivity = timeresult.input_data.outbuild(df, year, days)
```

#### Just running the files through the function:

- using `files` from above
- it's unclear whether `timeresult` takes a file or a dataframe

```py
for file in files:
    out_put, productivity = timeresult.input_data.outbuild(file, year, days)
    productivity.to_csv(file.name)
```

- If the function doesn't work with `pathlib` objects, replace `file` with `str(file)` in the function call

Comment: My only question now is there a way to have the index be the date name of the csv file like have the index be jan for the jan.csv used for the reference data?

Comment: If you have a `datetime` column, `df['month'] = df.datetime.dt.month_name()`, then `df.set_index('month', inplace=True)`.  If the date is not somewhere in the dataframe, then you'd have to add a month column by some other means.